# Laravel 5 - workbench migrations

Tags: laravel-5

Can anyone tell me how to create a migration in Laravel 5 for a workbench package?

Comment: I believe that Laravel 5 doesn't use workbench anymore

Comment: Yep. Laravel 5 got rid of workbench. You are free to use your own folder structure for building packages.